# Admin user is the same django user - how to solve this

Tags: django, authentication, view, django-admin, admin

When I built my e-commerce page, I noticed that if I am logged in with user 1, when I log in with user 2 no admin, my django page is automatically logged in with user 2.
I don't want this to happen.
I want to continue with user 1 on the django site even if logged in with user 2 in the admin. How could this be resolved?
Can someone help me please?

In my views.py:

```
def login_request(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)       
        if user is not None:  
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("store:index")
    elif not form.is_valid() and form.cleaned_data.get('username')!=None or form.cleaned_data.get('password')!=None:
        messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
    elif form.cleaned_data.get('username')==None and form.cleaned_data.get('password')==None:
        messages.error(request,"Please, enter your username and password.")
form =  AuthenticationForm()
return render(request=request, template_name="login//login.html", context={"login_form":form})
```

Comment: Pretty sure that django uses session authentication so that should mean that only one user can be logged in per browser and that if you try to log into another user that user will be switched. 
A possible solution could be removing session authentication and implementing token authentication or something similar.
Or, make your life easier and log one user in through an incognito window and the other through the normal one.

Comment: So, every time I authenticate via session, I log in to the admin and django. I didn't know. Thanks, Liam.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user to your home page if he is already logged in. It this way user can't be overridden in browser.

You can use middleware for this.

Sample Code:

```
class AuthRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index')) # or http response
        return None


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'path.to.your.AuthRequiredMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Hi Vinay, thank you very much for your information on how to solve my problem.